# import ontology into Cytoscape (3.8 Desktop)

Tags: ontology, cytoscape

I am working with non-biological data, and I was wondering if it is possible to import ontologies into Cytoscape 3.8? I see that older versions of Cytoscape allow for this (ex. 3.5). I really want to be able to map some of my data to items from ontologies or annotation-files; any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The older versions supported the loading of specific ontologies for data table annotation only (not for network construction). The web service that we relied on is no longer supported, so we removed that annotation function.

But the ability to import an ontology as a network remains the same. You have to find or restructure the ontology data into one of the many supported network data formats. SIF (simple interaction format) might be the... simplest. I don't know of any apps that directly import .obo for example, but they might exist.